# How to jump from page 1 to the specific section in page 2 if there are no anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html

How to jump from page 1 to the specific section in page 2 if there are no anchor tags in page 2 .. Tried with `<a href=#sectionname` but no sign of hope.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to no the x / y position of the section on page 2 but look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Should work provided you have those details.

Comment: actually in page 2 there are no id's, name or any anchor tags.. only the categories are unique too :(

Comment: yes you mentioned that, thats why i sent you a link to an example of a function that takes in numbers representing the X / Y of the page, not anchors, id's or names. a little trial and error should get you what you need not (sounds like a bad website design however, if it can it should be changed).

Comment: Thanks simon for the help .. trying to apply function :)

Answer (score 0):

in page 1 you should have a link (anchor tag) to page 2

```
<a href="page2.html#yoursection">
```

in page 2 you need to have a tag with id="yoursection" e.g.

```
<div id="yoursection">
```

that should work

Comment: hello bart , I understand, but the fact is that there are no id, name and any anchor tags.. the code looks something like this " <div class="sp_st">Salads &amp; Starters</div><div class="sp_i sp_in"><div class="sp_ip"><p>[[$13.00]] </p></div> "

Comment: if it is not possible to add such id, then I think you can only try some tricks with javascript. However, if you have a long page (a large menu with many starters) there's no way to uniquely identify your jump target. An id may only occur once in a html page therefore it's a unique identifier for jumping.

Comment: I see you are not in control of page 2. What you can try: Use jQuery and for each (.each()) class, add a generated id to the div that has the class. But that may become tricky